# Spherical harmonics, $\frak{sl}_2$, and algebra gradings

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, harmonic-analysis, spherical-geometry

Let $S^2$ be the usual $2$-sphere considered as the quotient $S^3/S^1$, and denote by $\operatorname{Pol}(S^2)$ the algebra of polynomial functions on $S^2$. We can decompose $\operatorname{Pol}(S^2)$ into its spherical harmonics, but here I would rather decompose them into simple $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-modules:
$$
\operatorname{Pol}(S^2) \simeq \bigoplus_{k \in 2\mathbb{N}} V_k,
$$
which is equivalently the decomposition into Laplacian eigenspaces. This decomposition surely must not be an algebra grading ($V_k\cdot V_l$ will surely not be contained in $V_{k+l}$). What is an easy way to prove this?

Comment: One could use the identity $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and the facts $x,y,z\in V_2, 1\in V_0$.

Comment: Where can I find an explicit expression of the irreducibles in terms of spherical harmonics?

Comment: Relatedly, what is the explicit action of the elements $E,F,H \in \frak{sl}_2$ on the generators $x,y,z$? I guess each is a weight vector, and depending on convention one is highest, one is lowest, and the other zero?

Comment: Aren't the spherical harmonics equal to the irreducible representations, since the eigenspaces of the Laplacian are necessarily stable under $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and the number of them is equal to the number of irreducible representations? I would say $X+ i Y$ is highest weight, $X - i Y$ is lowest weight, and $Z$ is zero.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are going directly to the harmonics on the $2$-sphere.  Instead, you could use the polynomial ring $R = \mathbb{R}[u,v]$ and let $E = u\,\partial/\partial v$, $F = v\,\partial/\partial u$, and $H=u\,\partial/\partial u-v\,\partial/\partial v$.  Then letting $V_k\subset R$ be the space of homogeneous terms of degree $k\ge0$ gives a splitting into irreducibles and, moreover, we do have $V_k\cdot V_l \subset V_{k+l}$.  Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @Robert: I am not so interested in finding an $\mathbb{N}$-grading, I am interested in the functions on the sphere. I want to be sure that the decomposition into irreps does not give the structure of a graded algebra. But by Will's comments, I guess this is true.